# how can i get the sold, removed, expired or ended items from eBay

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am creating a plugin which I need to get sold, removed, expired, or ended items like that bonanza Import setting.
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FabW.png)

I am already using **GetSellerList** Request. But I am unable to find these parameters. If any way or any other eBay API where I can get these parameters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>          
<GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
     <eBayAuthToken>Auth_Token</eBayAuthToken>
 </RequesterCredentials>
 <Pagination ComplexType="PaginationType">
     <EntriesPerPage>20</EntriesPerPage>
     <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
 </Pagination>
 <StartTimeFrom>user_id</StartTimeFrom>
 <StartTimeTo></StartTimeTo>
 <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
 <UserID>User_id</UserID>
</GetSellerListRequest>
```

Comment: Is https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/findCompletedItems.html what you are after?

Comment: Thank You for your response, but this is not what I found I want seller items list where I can get these types of products.

Comment: Don't have a clue what the *bonanza Import setting* is even supposed to be part of.  I'm sure a lot of others won't either.